# sorting array with uasort comparing to a string with regex

Tags: php, regex, string, sorting

I am trying to sort an array "$refs" by comparing it to a string "$term" using uasort and regex :

this is my array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 71063
            [uniqid] => A12171063
            [label] => Pratique...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 71067
            [uniqid] => A12171067
            [label] => Etre....
        )
...
```

and my code :

```
uasort($refs, function ($a, $b) use ($term) {
            $patern='/^' . $term . '/';  

            if ((preg_match($patern, $a['label']) - preg_match($patern, $b['label']) )== 0) {
                return 0;
            }

            if ((preg_match($patern, $a['label']) - preg_match($patern, $b['label'])) == 1) {
                return -1;
            }
            if ((preg_match($patern, $a['label']) - preg_match($patern, $b['label'])) == -1) {
                return 1;
            }
        });
```

I have only 0 like returns, where is my mistake !:/ 
Thanks

Comment: `$refs = $a = $b = $term = ???`

Comment: $refs is the array, and $term is the word to compare to

Comment: This is like a 1-liner in perl.. I can write something in Perl if that'd help

Comment: yes, why not , i'll take it as example . Thanks

Comment: Works fine [here](http://ideone.com/IomXWv). What's in the `$term`, I wonder? If it contains regex metacharacters, you probably need to `preg_quote` it.

Comment: no, it contains terms of an autocomplete search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Won't answer the question as stated but you could use this. It will effectively rank the results based on how close the term is to the beginning of the string.

```
function ($a, $b) use ($term) {
  return stripos($a, $term) - stripos($b, $term);
}
```

This will only work if all of the values have the term somewhere in them (like the results of a like query).

Test script:

```
$arr = array("aaTest", "aTest", "AAATest", "Test");
$term = "Test";
uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($term) {
  return stripos($a, $term) - stripos($b, $term);
});

print_r($arr);
```

Test Output:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Test
    [1] => aTest
    [0] => aaTest
    [2] => AAATest
)
```

**UPDATE**

Changed code to use stripos instead of strpos for case insensitive sorting

Comment: but i need theme to be at the begining !